# App.config file and section type

Tags: prism, app-config

I have a problem. I'm learning from MTaulty's video: http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/mtaulty/prism--silverlight-part-2-dependency-injection-with-unity. And I have a problem with **.config** file which he creates at 18:00 min. There is no possibility to see what is in

```
     <section type=".."
```

I wrote:

```
    type="Microsoft.Practises.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practises.Unity.Configuration" />
```

but it does not work. I don't have idea what is wrong. I have a mistake that VisualStudio can't load file'Microsoft.Practises.Unity.Configuration and find a file.

thanks for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to specify modules via config file the [Prism Guide on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405479%28v=pandp.40%29#sec21) does a good job explaining that.

Quote from the Guide

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="modules"
      type="Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.ModulesConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Prism"/>
  </configSections>
  <modules>
    <module assemblyFile="ModularityWithUnity.Desktop.ModuleE.dll" moduleType="ModularityWithUnity.Desktop.ModuleE, ModularityWithUnity.Desktop.ModuleE, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" moduleName="ModuleE" startupLoaded="false" />
     <module assemblyFile="ModularityWithUnity.Desktop.ModuleF.dll" moduleType="ModularityWithUnity.Desktop.ModuleF, ModularityWithUnity.Desktop.ModuleF, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" moduleName="ModuleF" startupLoaded="false">
      <dependencies>
        <dependency moduleName="ModuleE"/>
      </dependencies>
    </module>
  </modules>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

For Prism 6.0 section type has changed to **Prism.Modularity.ModulesConfigurationSection, Prism.Wpf**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="modules" type="Prism.Modularity.ModulesConfigurationSection, Prism.Wpf" />
  </configSections>
  <modules>    
   *** register your modules here ****
  </modules>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with App.config mapping. The section type was invalid. The right one is:

```
<section name="modules" type="Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.ModulesConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Prism.**Composition**"/>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: <section name="modules"     type="Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.ModulesConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Composition"/>